# How to pass a path param / uri param from Mule 4 to SFDC via APEX call?

Tags: salesforce, mule, apex, mulesoft, mule4

I am migrating an existing Mule 3 application to Mule 4

Mule 3 is making an APEX GET call and passing a `path param / uri param` as well as a `query param`

Here is the source code for Mule 3:

```
<sfdc:invoke-apex-rest-method config-ref="SFDC_config" 
restMethodName="EmpMaintenanceDetails||getEmpMaintenanceDetails^/services/apexrest/EmpMaintenanceDetails/
#[flowVars.empId]?id=#[flowVars.empId]^HttpGet^application/json^" doc:name="Salesforce: EmpMaintenanceDetails"/>
```

So here `flowVars.empId` is the path param and `id=#[flowVars.empId]` is the same value passes as a query param

In case of Mule 4 I was able to pass the query param in dataweave:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="set empId as query param" >
<ee:message >
    <ee:set-payload >
        <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
            output application/json
            ---
            {
                queryParams:{
                    id: message.attributes.uriParams.'empId'
                }
            }]]>
    </ee:set-payload>
</ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

However I am not sure how to pass the path / uri param ?

In case of Mule 4 in anypoint studio the method name is auto populated so this is the code I have for Mule 4 :

```
<salesforce:invoke-apex-rest-method doc:name="SF EmpMaintenanceDetails GET call" 
config-ref="SFDC_config" className="EmpMaintenanceDetails"
methodName="getEmpMaintenanceDetails^/EmpMaintenanceDetails/*^HttpGet^void^" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `EmpMaintenanceDetails/*` in the method name with a data weave expression to get the variable:

```
EmpMaintenanceDetails/#[vars.empId]
```

I think the auto population just adds a wildcard for the uri param by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
"getEmpMaintenanceDetails^/EmpMaintenanceDetails/" ++ attributes.uriParams.empId ++ "^HttpGet^void^"
```